# Массив случайных чисел с диапазоном значений определенной суммы php

Tags: php, массивы, случайные-числа

Задача создать массив случайных чисел определенной длины, с заданным диапазоном чисел, чтобы в сумме было определенное значение.
К примеру, нужно 5 чисел, с диапазоном 5-20, в сумме 50.
На выходе нужно что-то типа 6, 12, 13, 8, 11.

Для тех, кто будет искать решение подобной задачи, пока единственное такое (можно сразу и забрать себе):

```
function array_rand_with_sum($min, $max, $sum, $num)
{
   $a = array();
   if ($max*$num > $sum && $min < $sum\$num)
   {
      do
      {
         for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i ++)
         {
            $a[$i] = mt_rand($min, $max);
         }
      }
      while(array_sum($a) != $sum);
      return $a;
   }
   else { return "Ошибка! Проверьте входные данные."; }
}
```

Если кто-то найдет лучше - буду очень рад!

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? В получении случайных чисел?

Comment: Мм. Проблема описана немного выше, получить случайно число - не проблема. Даже массив случайных чисел и даже определенной длины. Нужно, чтобы была определенная сумма этих чисел.

Comment: Вас устроит неравномерное распределение вероятности?

Comment: Можно попробовать "в лоб": если сумма не равна искомой - генерить числа заново. Вполне возможно 20-30 итераций будет хватать.

Comment: @Nofate, в принципе, устроит, смотря, что за этим стоит :))

Comment: @Владимир, если честно - это первая мысль, которая пришла в голову, но по-моему это как-то ресурсоемко и топорно. Хотя, если не найду более подходящий вариант - придется использовать этот.

Comment: Зато числа более "натуральные" :-)

Comment: Согласен, и кстати, не так уж и долго и ресурсоемко, как я ожидал, для моих запросов. Хотя там раз на раз не приходится.
Вот такой набор:
$min = 2;
$max = 100;
$num = 10;
$sum = 700;
генерит от 1 до 100 мс(тестировал всего 10 раз, но все же)
и получается вот такой набор:
93
77
53
51
43
66
70
83
94
70
А метод товарища @myvzar иногда выбивается из диапазона и генерит вот такой набор:
99
87
396
31
21
16
15
14
11
10

примерно за то же время(немного меньше).

Answer (score 2):

Надеяться, что ваша функция завершиться весьма опрометчиво, попробуйте такие входные параметры:

```
array_rand_with_sum(1, 1000, 10000, 200);
```

У меня из десятка попыток ни разу не удалось получить результат.

Мой вариант функции примерно такой:

```
function array_rand_with_sum($min, $max, $sum, $num)
{
    if ($num <= 0 || $max * $num < $sum || $min * $num > $sum) {
        return "Ошибка! Проверьте входные данные.";
    }
    if ($num == 1) {
        return [$sum];
    }
    $rand = mt_rand(
        max($min, $sum - $max * ($num - 1)),
        min($max, $sum - $min * ($num - 1))
    );
    $res = array_rand_with_sum($min, $max, $sum - $rand, $num - 1);
    $res[] = $rand;
    return $res;
}

$res = array_rand_with_sum(1, 1000, 10000, 200);
if (is_array($res)) {
    var_dump([
        'min' => min($res),
        'max' => max($res),
        'sum' => array_sum($res),
        'count' => count($res),
    ]);
}
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Отличный метод, как по мне, по скорости исполнения, но из 200 176 значений - "2". Потом пяток "3", а потом остаток от 86 до 950.

Comment: суть в том, что он гарантированно работает, для $min = 2; $max = 100; $num = 10; $sum = 700 результаты у меня примерно такие: [49,81,67,75,79,71,56,88,94,40]

Comment: кстати, там у меня в функции с проверкой, наверное, беда. я долго ее мучал, но бессонная ночь не идет на пользу логическому мышлению :) поэтому пока оставлю так, а потом подправлю. или если кто найдет ошибку, пусть пишут.
я пока использую свой вариант, так как пока по скорости и качеству он меня устраивает, ну а любой заинтересовавшийся может использовать тот метод, который ему по душе, протестировав и выбрав из тех, что тут имеются. чуть позже, может и я что-то придумаю новое. :)

Answer (score -1):

Не красиво, но как вариант

```
    function array_rand_with_sum($min, $max, $sum, $num)
{
    $return = array();
    $newsum = $sum;
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
        $c = rand($min,($max<$newsum)?$max:$newsum);
        $newsum -= $c;
        $return[]= $c;
    }
    $array_sum = array_sum($return);
    arsort($return);
    if($array_sum>$sum) {
        $return[0]-= ($array_sum-$sum);
    } else {
        $return[count($return)-1]+= ($sum-$array_sum);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Интересно комментарий, почему минус...

Comment: Минус не мой, я наоборот поддерживаю любые ответы и первым делом как увидел побежал тестировать. :)
Чуть выше в комментах показал результаты, немного не так работает функция как надо.